# UPDATE FROM SELECT (correct duplicate values)

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

The table TEST is wrong because it has duplicate values. I need to update the relational table with an unique id for test and then delete the duplicated values.

TEST

```
+----------+---------+
| id_test  |  name   |
+----------+---------+
|    1     |   gir   |
|    2     |   gir   |  
|    3     |   gir   |
|    4     |   ego   |
|    5     |   ego   |
|    6     |   iph   |
|    7     |   iph   |
+----------+---------+
```

PRODUCT_HAS_TEST

```
+----------+---------+
| id_prod  | id_test |
+----------+---------+
|    3     |    1    |
|    1     |    2    |  
|    2     |    2    |
|    4     |    3    |
|    5     |    4    |
|    6     |    5    |
|    7     |    6    |
|    8     |    7    |
+----------+---------+
```

I have this query to find duplicate values:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id_test) as ids, name, COUNT(*) c FROM test GROUP BY name HAVING c > 1;
```

Result:

```
+------+------+------+
| ids  | name |   c  |
+------+------+------+
| 4,5  | ego  |   2  |
|1,2,3 | gir  |   3  |
| 6,7  | iph  |   2  |
+------+------+------+
```

And another one to delete duplicate values from TEST:

```
delete
from test using test,
    test e1
where test.id > e1.id
    and test.name = e1.name
```

But I need to update the table PRODUCT_HAS_TEST first and I don't know how to do it.

Expected result:

PRODUCT_HAS_TEST

```
+----------+---------+
| id_prod  | id_test |
+----------+---------+
|    3     |    1    |
|    1     |    1    |  
|    2     |    1    |
|    4     |    1    |
|    5     |    4    |
|    6     |    4    |
|    7     |    6    |
|    8     |    6    |
+----------+---------+
```

TEST

```
+----------+---------+
| id_test  |  name   |
+----------+---------+
|    1     |   gir   |
|    4     |   ego   |
|    6     |   iph   |
+----------+---------+
```

Comment: Can you show us what you want both of the tables to look like after the update?

Comment: Sure! I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you want to `retain the min id_test` value when id_test is duplicate,if it's true then you can use below srcipt :

logic :
1. using mysql update join with query for `duplicate id_test mapping min_id_test` then update id_test by min_id_test
2. delete TEST table duplicate id_test when the id_test is not min_id_test

> ```
> CREATE TABLE TEST
>   (`id_test` int, `name` varchar(3))
> ;
>
> INSERT INTO TEST
>   (`id_test`, `name`)
> VALUES
>   (1, 'gir'),(2, 'gir'),(3, 'gir'),(4, 'ego'),(5, 'ego'),(6, 'iph'),(7, 'iph');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE PRODUCT_HAS_TEST
>   (`id_prod` int, `id_test` int)
> ;
>
> INSERT INTO PRODUCT_HAS_TEST
>   (`id_prod`, `id_test`)
> VALUES
>   (3, 1),(1, 2),(2, 2),(4, 3),(5, 4),(6, 5),(7, 6),(8, 7);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE PRODUCT_HAS_TEST as T1
> join (
>   select T1.*,T2.id_test as new_id_test from TEST T1
>   join (
>       select min(id_test) id_test,name
>       from TEST 
>       where id_test is not null
>       group by name
>   ) T2 on T1.name = T2.name
>   where T1.id_test <> T2.id_test
> )T2 on T1.id_test = T2.id_test
> set T1.id_test = T2.new_id_test
> where T2.new_id_test is not null
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> DELETE FROM TEST as T 
> where T.id_test not in (
>     select * from (
>         select distinct min(id_test) 
>         from TEST 
>         group by name
>     ) T2
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from PRODUCT_HAS_TEST;
> ```
>
> ```
> id_prod | id_test
> ------: | ------:
>       3 |       1
>       1 |       1
>       2 |       1
>       4 |       1
>       5 |       4
>       6 |       4
>       7 |       6
>       8 |       6
> ```

> ```
> select * from TEST;
> ```
>
> ```
> id_test | name
> ------: | :---
>       1 | gir 
>       4 | ego 
>       6 | iph
> ```

### *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=27389de8195fbc584674082fb1eca4b5)*